# IPs that don't have subnet mask

Tags: ip, subnet

I'm new to networking. I know that some IPs don't have a sub net mask like 127.0.0.1 and the range that starts with 127. I wanted to know if there is any other IPs that don't have sub net mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP addresses don't have subnet masks.  Networks do.   For the loopback address, the entire /8 is reserved, so it's  127.0.0.0/8 or 255.0.0.0.

Comment: So the IPs that have 127 as their first octet, have netmask too? For example for 127.0.25.1, the netmask is 255.0.0.0?

Comment: @Pablo The reserved loopback is 127.0.0.0/8, so you can use any address from 127.0.0.1 to 127.255.255.254.

Comment: The loopback address is a special reserved case (See RFC 1122).